# How do you tell when the end of a command is in an inline command in redis?

Tags: redis

I was reading the [redis protocol](http://redis.io/topics/protocol) and it says that you can send inline command with telnet by using "space-separated arguments in a telnet session". I had a few question about this

1) How does a redis-server know where the command ends if its space-separated? Does it end at `\r\n`? Since its not length prefixed I can't think of a different way. Maybe EOF...

2) If it ends with `\r\n` or something similar and is not length prefixed, does that mean that its not binary safe anymore (when the client sends inline commands)? i.e. if a client decides to send an inline command, it can no longer send any arbitrary character/byte it wishes?

3) Can any redis command be sent via telnet (with the only restriction that its not binary safe anymore) or is this only restricted to a PING? For example, a set would be:

`SET key value\r\n`

but `SET key\r\n value\r\n` is not allowed anymore (you are allowed to send that but the redis-server should sent a syntax error).

Comment: I believe yes on all three. You can test 3 with telnet yourself ;)

Comment: I will, I think its done like this `(echo -en "PING\r\n"; sleep 1) | nc localhost 6379`, Ill try it out...